# Cypress beforeEach setup with cy.request

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

My tests require creating some items in database so before each test I make few requests to API to create them using `cy.request()`

Is it good practice or I should prepare setup some other way?

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.request(someUrl)
  cy.request(anotherUrl)
})

it('test smth', () => {
  // do some stuff
})

it('test something', () => {
  // do some stuff
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a good practice. Read more [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/testing-your-app#Seeding-data). Also, you can watch a brilliant presentation by Brian Mann [here](http://youtube.com/watch?v=5XQOK0v_YRE).

Keep in mind that tests should always be able to be run independently from one another and still pass. Read more [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Having-tests-rely-on-the-state-of-previous-tests).